# GuildChannel doesn't have members property

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to get list of connected users in a specific channel on `voiceStateUpdate` with this way:

```
module.exports = async (client, oldState, newState) => {
  const channel = await newState.guild.channels.fetch('719030671384772609');
}
```

but I don't see `members` property when checking the collections,

```
  'channelid' => <ref *8> VoiceChannel {
    type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
    deleted: false,
    guild: Guild {
    },
    guildId: '',
    parentId: '',
    permissionOverwrites: PermissionOverwriteManager { channel: [Circular *8] },
    id: '',
    name: '',
    rawPosition: 2,
    rtcRegion: 'hongkong',
    bitrate: 64000,
    userLimit: 0
  },
```

Did I miss something here? or an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can get a list of all connected users using something like this

```
newState.guild.channels.cache.get("channelID here").members
```

[relevant Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel)

Comment: Thanks, it works! never thought of "get" function here because in docs only said its a property, is there a doc related to "get" on cache?

Comment: There’s [This](https://anidiots.guide/v/v13/understanding/collections) and [This](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection)